# Extension of a bounded linear map

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $K \subset H$ both be Hilbert spaces. I'm trying to prove that for any bounded linear map $T: K \to X$ with $X$ a normed space, there exists an extension $\tilde{T}: H \to X$ such that the norm is preserved ($||T|| = ||\tilde{T}||$). Many of the answers I find on the internet about this have the extra condition that $X$ is Banach, I'm not able to come up with a solution when $X$ is not. What I tried so far is the following:

1. Extend $T: K -> X$ to $\bar{T}: \bar{K} \to \tilde{X}$ where $\bar{K}$ is the closure of the Hilbert subspace $X$ and $\tilde{X}$ is the completion of the normed space $X$ as we can always associate a Banach space to a normed space. Recalling that $K$ is dense in $\bar{K}$ this gives us an extension via the BLT.
2. Project $H$ onto the closed convex subset $\bar{K}$; $P_{\bar{K}}: H \to \bar{K}$
3. Taking the composition of these two maps we get a map $\bar{T} \circ P_\bar{K}: H \to \tilde{X}$.
4. I think I have to add a map to this to go from $\tilde{X} \to X$ or somehow be able to prove that any complete space gets mapped to a complete space under $T$ (which is not true I think).

Besides proving this I am also trying to find a pair of normed spaces $Y \subset X$, a two-dimensional normed space $Z$ and a bounded linear map $S: Y \to Z$ such that any extension $\tilde{S}: X \to Z$ satisfies $||\tilde{S}|| > ||S||$ indicating that the norm preservation relies on both $K \subset H$ being Hilbert spaces and not just normed spaces. I am also unable to come up with this but I think being able to complete the proof will help with this part too.

Answer (score 2):

We start out with the assumption that $K$ is Hilbert, which includes completeness in its definition. Therefore $K$ is already a closed convex subset of $H$ and step 1 is not needed. Just compose projection of $H$ onto $K$ with $T$ to get the desired map.

$$H \stackrel{P_K}{\to} K\stackrel{T}{\to} X$$

Comment: Ah yes! I overlooked that fact, I got it worked out now, thanks a lot :). For the second part (finding normed spaces such that the norm is greater), my proof of the norm preservation rests on the fact that the projection has norm 1. But that requires my space to be Hilbert so that's where it will go wrong. I'm not sure what to look for in such an example as I'm not sure what the extension would like. Any chance you could give me a hint? :)